# Is this the Flutter recommended way of writing code for variables declared final?

Tags: flutter, dart

We can use the following code in Flutter:

```
final String a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
```

However, should we use the following code instead of the above:

```
final String a;
final String b;
final String c;
final String d;
final String e;
final String f;
final String g;
```

You can see that the first code uses only 1 line and the second code uses 7 lines. So, I think we should use the first code instead of the second?

If you need more info feel free to leave a comment!

Is this the Flutter recommended way of writing code for variables declared `final`? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do the same thing. Write it how you want.

```
final String a = "one", b = "two", c = "three";
```

Or

I think this is easier to read when initializing variables:

```
final String a = "one";
final String b = "two";
final String c = "three";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you say which code format you recommend more?

Comment: @MyCar I think writing it on multiple lines is easier to read.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and share your thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I've accepted and upvoted this answer :)